# Как использовать переменые подстановки в динамическом запросе с клаузой INTO?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Eсть вопрос о том, где можно использовать переменные подстановки в динамическом SQL-операторе в PL/SQL.

Например, знаю, что так верно:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_num_of_employees (p_loc VARCHAR2, p_job VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
  v_query_str VARCHAR2(1000);
  v_num_of_employees NUMBER;
BEGIN
  v_query_str := 'SELECT COUNT(*) 
                  FROM emp_'||p_loc||' WHERE job = :bind_job';                          
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query_str
    INTO v_num_of_employees
    USING p_job;
  RETURN v_num_of_employees;
END;
/
```

Но интересно, возможно ли использовать переменные подстановки в подобном выражении:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_num_of_employees (p_loc VARCHAR2, p_job VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
  v_query_str VARCHAR2(1000);
  v_num_of_employees NUMBER;
BEGIN
  v_query_str := 'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :into_bind 
                  FROM emp_'||p_loc||' WHERE job = :bind_job';                          
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query_str
    USING out v_num_of_employees, p_job;
  RETURN v_num_of_employees;
END;
/
```

Заметьте, что используется `SELECT...INTO` в динамическом запросе, и есть переменная подстановки в `INTO`.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Using bind variables with dynamic SELECT INTO clause in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7816402) от участника [@BYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/864629/bys2)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/7816402

Answer (score 3):

Надо различать, в каком контексте выполняется динамический запрос. То есть, какой интерпретатор выполняет подстановку в местозаполнители для переменных подстановки.

Несколько упростим и видоизменим первый пример из вопроса:

```
declare
    qry varchar2 (32767);
    cnt int := 7;
    num int;
begin
    qry := 'select count(*) into :dummy
            from dual connect by level<=:b1';                           
    execute immediate qry using cnt;
    dbms_output.put_line ('result>>'||num||'<<');
end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

result>><<
```

Всё отработало без ошибок, не результата запрос не вернул.

Дело в том, что в SQL `SELECT...INTO` синтактически верный запрос, но все местозаполнители после `INTO` игнорируются. Заметьте, в запросе два местозаполнителя: `:dummy` и `:b1`, а в `USING` только одна переменная. То есть, местозаполнитель `:dummy` вообще не участвует в запросе.

Результат запроса может быть получен только через переменные в клаузе `INTO` самого `EXECUTE`, и т.к. эта клауза не обязательна, то запрос выполнится, но ничего не вернёт.

Когда же имеет смысл `SELECT...INTO` в динамическом запросе. Если обернуть запрос в блок `BEGIN...END`, то подстановку местозаполнителя `:b1` будет выполнять интерпретатор PL/SQL. Например, так будет работать:

```
declare
    qry varchar2 (32767);
    cnt int := 7;
    num int;
begin
    qry := 'begin
            select count(*) into :b1
            from dual connect by level<=:b2;
        end;';                           
    execute immediate qry using out num, cnt;
    dbms_output.put_line ('result>>'||num||'<<');
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

result>>7<<
```